# Python virtual-environment and py file doesn't start when run batch file from c#

Tags: c#, python, batch-file, virtualenv

I have a batch file that has these commands to start a virtual environment and run a python file. when I start batch files manually through CMD it is running as expected. I have a different program (.NET web application) to start this batch file and arguments are passed from the web application to the batch file. However, the batch file takes the arguments but doesn't start the virtual-environment or python file.

```
@echo on
set filename="D:\test.txt"
echo %1_%2_%3 >%filename%

set root=C:\Users\TMF\Anaconda3
call %root%\Scripts\activate.bat %root%
call activate sales_analysis
C:\Users\TMF\Anaconda3\envs\sales_analysis\python.exe D:/sales/prediction_client.py %1 %2 %3
pause
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few hours of google search,I found that there are some restrictions with the default IIS user (usually it’s called “ApplicationPoolIdentity”).So I created a new service account on the server and assign my web application to new user and  restart the application pool.After that batch file was able to start the python process as expected.